# Next JS app error of module cjs is not supported

Tags: next.js, module

I am using next app version 13.0.04 and I added packages `@lens-protocol/wagmi` and `wagmi` but I am getting this error when I want to run the app:

> error - unhandledRejection: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES
> Module /.../node_modules/wagmi/dist/index.js from
> /.../node_modules/@lens-protocol/wagmi/dist/lens-protocol-wagmi.cjs.dev.js
> not supported. Instead change the require of index.js in
> /.../node_modules/@lens-protocol/wagmi/dist/lens-protocol-wagmi.cjs.dev.js
> to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

This is how my next.config.js looks like:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack']
    });
    return config;
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

How could I resolve this and make the package works in the next app?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it by adding `transpilePackages` with the package name to the `next.config.js` file and upgrading the `next` js from `13.0.4` to `13.16.1` as the old version didn't support the transpilePackages configuration:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  transpilePackages: ['@lens-protocol'],
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```